# cannot convert from 'to'?

Tags: c#, ado.net

this error appear [image]

**i have this error  cannot convert from 'to' **

```
    using SCB_Common.ExtensionMethods;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SCB_Common.DataBase
{
    public class BusinessCommon
    {
        public static void SetCommonCloumns(SqlDataReader DR, EntityCommon entity)
        {
            entity.CreatedAt = DR.GetDateTime("CreatedAt");
            entity.CreatedBy = DR.GetDecimal("CreatedBy");

            entity.LastModifyAt = DR.GetDateTime("LastModifyAt");
            entity.LastModifyBy = DR.GetDecimal("LastModifyBy");
            entity.ModifyBy = DR.GetDecimal("ModifyBy");

            entity.PostStateAt = DR.GetDateTime("PostStateAt");
            entity.PostStateBy = DR.GetDecimal("PostStateBy");

            entity.RecordState = DR.GetInt32("RecordState");
            entity.I_D = DR.GetDecimal("I_D");
        }
    }
}
```

**this is the the method get record when i call  SCB_Common.DataBase.BusinessCommon.SetCommonCloumns(DR, entity);
 **

```
 public Entity.SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity GetRecord(Entity.SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity ent, out bool IsDeleted)
    {
        IsDeleted = true;
        Entity.SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity entity = null;

        SqlDataReader DR = Action.GetDataList(ent, 1, 1, "");
        while (DR.Read())
        {
            IsDeleted = false;

            entity = new Entity.SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity();
            entity.ID = DR.GetDecimal("ID");
            entity.Aname = DR.GetString("Aname");
            entity.Ename = DR.GetString("Ename");

            SCB_Common.DataBase.BusinessCommon.SetCommonCloumns(DR, entity);
        }
        DR.Close();

        return entity;
    }
```

**this is the class entity**

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SCB_HR_Business.Entity
{
   public class SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity
    {
        public decimal ID_Co
        { get; set; }

        public decimal ID
        { get; set; }
        public string Aname
        { get; set; }
        public string Ename
        { get; set; }
        public decimal I_D
        { get; set; }

        public object LastModifyBy { get; set; }

        public object CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity` relate to `Entity`? Obviously you pass an instance of the former where the latter is required on `SetCommonCloumns`.

Comment: i edit the questiont

Comment: `SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity` doesn't appear to derive from `EntityCommon`, which is what the second parameter of `SetCommonCloumns` is meant to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity` is not a `EntityCommon`, I mean, it does not inheriths from `EntityCommon`. The method `SetCommonCloumns` except as a second argument a `EntityCommon` object. Try it out:

```
public class SBH_D_Guardianship_Type_Entity : EntityCommon 
{
    public decimal ID_Co { get; set; }

    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public string Aname { get; set; }
    public string Ename { get; set; }
    public decimal I_D { get; set; }
}
```

And remember to remove the properties you have defined on the `EntityCommon`.